# How to comment a string containing */

Tags: php, comments, syntax-error

I have a line of PHP source code I would like to keep in a PHP file as a comment, so it can be used when necessary. This is only a debugging script, so keeping the file clean is not an issue.

Nevertheless, I am trying to comment these lines using `/*` and `*/`:

```
/*
$path = FOLDER . "*/*/*/*/*.gif";
$files = glob($path);
*/
```

But this result in a parse error, because the path `*/*/*/` closes the comment block. An opening `/*` won't be treated as an opening comment inside a string, but since the commented code is not parsed, the `*/` is treated as a closing comment.

Can anyone can think of a workaround without using `//`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `"*/*/*/*/*.gif"` slashes as `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant?

```
$path = FOLDER . '*' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '*' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR  . '.gif';
```

You can make a shortcut like `define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);`

Answer (score 1):

Just use a backslash `\` before ever forwardslash `/`. It won't not affect the file path but will make the lines block commentable.

Comment: No. The backslashes will be included in the final string.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use `//` or a method like message or bluegman991 suggested.

> 'C' style comments end at the first */ encountered. <sup>[1](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.comments.php)</sup>

The interpreter terminates the comment at the first `*/` regardless of whether it is part of a string or nested comment.

Your IDE may have a shortcut to toggle `//` comments on blocks of code.  For example, Eclipse uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to toggle comments on blocks of code.

Comment: I deleted my answer of using `goto` for fear of being downvoted back to a score of 1. However, it is the only way to bypass blocks of code that use multi-line comments. For this particular question, I think it's best to just rewrite the string. +1 for using IDE to apply the single line comments.

Comment: @webbiedave Clever answer IMO but I understand your fears.  Anti-goto indoctrination has been strong for longer than I've been programming :)

Comment: @drew010 I saw your solution I think it was perfectly valid. The only drawback I could see is that it would not be highlighted as a commented section in my IDE (eclipse) and would be easier to forget. But I understand your fear :)

Comment: (I got confused my comment was intended for @webbiedave)

Comment: I figured that :) However, my solution was just for use during a debugging session, not for comments that will remain in source.

Answer (score 0):

for any special character you wanna use inside a string you can use \ without affecting on the behaviour of this string

Answer (score 0):

I personally often use:

```
if (false) {  
    ...code to be skipped...  
}
```

This way you should avoid the problem, but missing the highlighting from your ide (unless it is a very very very smart ide :))